# Ordering of Spring Security annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, aop, spring-4

If a method has multiple security annotations, in what order are they applied?

For example, is it the order in which the annotations are defined, or is it fixed such that e.g. `SecuredAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource` is always used before `PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource`?

Put another way, what is the evaluation order when calling these methods?

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#target, 'read')")
void method1();

@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#target, 'read')")
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
void method2();

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') && hasPermission(#target, 'read')")
void method3();

@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#target, 'read') && hasRole('ADMIN')")
void method4();
```

Comment: A reason for the downvote would be nice. What can be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr: Mixing `@Secured` and `@PreAuthorize` *does not work*.**

As detailed [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2116), the method security interceptor stops once it has found the first supported annotation.

```
for (MethodSecurityMetadataSource s : methodSecurityMetadataSources) {
    attributes = s.getAttributes(method, targetClass);
    if (attributes != null && !attributes.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

> it's intentional that `DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource` only uses one source of metadata, the first which returns a non-null result

The ordering is `@PreAuthorize` ≻ `@Secured` ≻ `@RolesAllowed`. Therefore methods one and two in the question are actually equivalent to

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#target, 'read')")
void method();
```

i.e. the `@Secured` annotation is silently ignored.